# Utility Application infoButton Stays on Top

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I used a utility application template to create my application, but I am using a UIImagePicker to pick some photos. The little infoButton, the i with a circle around it, shows up when the picker is displayed. If the infoButton was not in another class then I could call infoButton.hidden = YES; and it would hide it. Any ideas how to solve this problem?
Thanks,
-Pat

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?  There are certainly ways around this, but I'm confused by what you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at the utility application template, the view controller with a gray background and an info button is MainViewController, and the instance is also the "mainViewController" property of the application delegate.

It seems that you have already created an IBOutlet to the infoButton, so, you can access the button by calling [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.mainViewController.infoButton .